# Closing > Off-Topic dialog could use some more formatting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, user-interface, close-dialog

[image]

I find the "**asking for code to be written**" being bold, makes it easy to spot that close reason at a glance.

It would be nice if the dialog also bolded key words in the other close reasons, like:

- Questions must **include the code you want reviewed**. [...]
- Questions must **contain working code** for use to review [...]
- This question **belongs on another site**  in the StackExchange network.

Comment: Based on 5 upvotes and no downvotes, I'll make this change on Monday or so if it isn't already done.

Answer (score 2):

The formatting has been improved as per the suggestion.
However, the *This question belongs on another site in the StackExchange network* close reason cannot be changed as it is universal across all StackExchange sites.